# How do I paint rough drywall?

Tags: drywall, painting, paint

The drywall is not smooth.  What is the best way to paint this?  Using a roller does not apply the paint evenly.

Why is it like this?

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to be like this? I'm wondering if it is a design or a manufacturing mistake.

Comment: no idea why this is like this

Comment: I suspect it is a spray on pattern and not straight up drywall. I think you'll need to sand it smooth before you can paint it with a roller, or you rent a sprayer.

Comment: See Bob Vila on drywall textures: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/wall-texture-types/. As for what to do, there are some choices: Sand, a messy operation that might damage the paper wallboard coating; removing the wallboard and replacing it; covering with another layer of wallboard; or learn to appreciate that pattern.

Comment: If following the answers doesn't help then add pictures of your roller and the uneven result.

Comment: "Why is it like this" is a separate question that should be asked separately.

Answer (score 4):

Use a roller cover with a longer nap (fiber length from the core) to paint a textured surface with a roller.

If you don't want the texture, that's a different question. It's pretty clearly a deliberately applied texture. There are many reasons for using texture, most of which have to do with fooling the eye (it's harder to see where the surface is not flat if it's textured.)

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a variation of orange peel texture sprayed on drywall.

There is no reason a 3/8 nap roller will not apply paint to the wall.  Here in Florida there are hundreds of thousands of homes with that or similar texture on the walls. They are painted every day with rollers and brush.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the OPs painting technique, not the surface or the tool...

Comment: @ FreeMan,  the technique would have to be exceptionally bad. You know a monkey with a 3/8 nap roller would be able to paint that wall.  Then again I don't know of some peoples' skills.  I had a teen on one job site that honestly didn't know how to use a broom.

Comment: I had a coworker come help with a project once. He wasn't sure how to use a hammer. We limited him to simple tasks like fetching drinks.

Comment: Thanks for being very courteous @RMDman.